# Looping through a string and only returning certain characters. Python

Tags: python

I have a problem when creating a function that's supposed to first return lowercase letters, "_" and "." and then uppercase letters, " " and "|" in that order. My version seems to return numbers and special characters like <>@ too which I don't want it to do, It's only supposed to read through the input string once and I don't know if that's achieved with my code.

My code is:

```
def split_iterative(n):
    splitted_first = ""
    splitted_second = ""
    for i in n:
        if i == i.lower() or i == "_" or i == ".":
            splitted_first = splitted_first + i
        elif i == i.upper() or i == " " or i == "|":
            splitted_second = splitted_second + i
    return splitted_first + splitted_second
```

if I do s`plit_iterative("'lMiED)teD5E,_hLAe;Nm,0@Dli&Eg ,#4aI?rN@T§&e7#4E #<(S0A?<)NT8<0'"))` it returns `"'li)te5,_he;m,0@li&g ,#4a?r@§&e7#4 #<(0?<)8<0'MEDDELANDEINTESANT"` which is incorrect as it should eliminate all those special characters and numbers. How do I fix this? It should return `('lite_hemligare', 'MEDDELANDE INTE SANT')`

Comment: The problem is i.lower() and i.upper() returns the same output when given a number or a special character.

Comment: It might be a case for a regular expression character class, something like `[\w. |]`, then a custom sort to get the required order.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
def f(input_string):
    str1 = str2 = ""
    for character in input_string:
        if character.isalpha():
            if character.islower():
                str1 += character
            else:
                str2 += character
        elif character in "_.":
            str1 += character
        elif character in " |":
            str2 += character
    return str1, str2
```

Output:

```
>>> input_string = "'lMiED)teD5E,_hLAe;Nm,0@Dli&Eg ,#4aI?rN@T§&e7#4E #<(S0A?<)NT8<0'"
>>> 
>>> print f(input_string)
('lite_hemligare', 'MEDDELANDE INTE SANT')
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The description isn't 100% clear, I thought `_` should come after lower case letters. Your method looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are iterating through a string. The lowercase of the special characters is the same as the character. i.e.. `'#'.lower() == '#'`. hence it'll return '#' and all other special characters. you should explicitly check for alphabets using the isalpha() method on strings.
`(i.isalpha() and i.lower() == i) or i == '_' or i == '.'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII values for the filtering of characters:

```
def split_iterative(n):
    splitted_first = ""
    splitted_second = ""
    for i in n:
        if ord(i) in range(97,122) or i == "_" or i == ".":
            splitted_first = splitted_first + i
        elif ord(i) in range(65,90) or i == " " or i == "|":
            splitted_second = splitted_second + i
    return (splitted_first , splitted_second)
```

Comment: change the last line to `return (splitted_first , splitted_second)` if you want a tuple instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

First, to make it return a list don't return the concatenated string but a list

Second, you are not checking or filtering out the characters, one way would be by checking if the character is a letter using isalpha() method

something like this:

```
def split_iterative(n):
splitted_first = ""
splitted_second = ""
for i in n:
    if (i.isalpha() and i == i.lower()) or i == "_" or i == ".":
        splitted_first = splitted_first + i
    elif (i.isalpha() and i == i.upper()) or i == " " or i == "|":
        splitted_second = splitted_second + i
#returns a list you can make it a variable if you need
return [splitted_first, splitted_second]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of two lists while walking through characters of your text.

You can append lowercase, underscore, and stop characters to one list then uppercase, space and pipe characters to the other.

Finally return a tuple of each list joined as strings.

```
def splittext(txt):
  slug, uppercase_letters = [], []
  slug_symbols = {'_', '.'}
  uppercase_symbols = {' ', '|'}

  for letter in txt:
    if letter.islower() or letter in slug_symbols:
      slug.append(letter)
    if letter.isupper() or letter in uppercase_symbols:
      uppercase_letters.append(letter)

  return ''.join(slug), ''.join(uppercase_letters)


txt="'lMiED)teD5E,_hLAe;Nm,0@Dli&Eg ,#4aI?rN@T§&e7#4E #<(S0A?<)NT8<0'"
assert splittext(txt) == ("lite_hemligare", "MEDDELANDE INTE SANT")
```

Comment: I'm not sure which operations are to blame but this solution is more than twice as slow as my solution although I'm abusing `+=` to do string concatenation. `>>> timeit.timeit(f) 10.171846151351929` vs. `>>> timeit.timeit(splittext) 22.767919063568115`. I'm using Python 2.7.12 on 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: I think that may be happening because those sets are created every time in the loop.

Comment: Aha, if you replace the sets with strings, your method becomes ~8 seconds faster. 14.916232824325562 vs. 22.767919063568115.

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm not seeing any performance gain by taking the static string out of the loop in my solution. Either I messed up the timeit test or Python optimizes the code behind the scenes.

Comment: Python makes the string once. So every time it re-uses the same string. ```s = "jDo"; g = "jDo"; assert id(s) == id(g)```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it but I thought the same would happen with immutable sets up to a certain size.

Comment: The same isn't happening with <ss>immutable</ss> sets. A new set object is created every time. `s = {'j', 'D', 'o'}; g = {'j', 'D', 'o'}; assert id(s) == id(g)`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Those sets aren't immutable.

Comment: @jDo Try `import dis; dis.dis(compile("a = {'_', '.'}; b = '_.'", '', 'exec'))`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You're right. Set's aren't immutable data types.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule At least not the `set` sets.

Comment: True true, I "misspoke"; regular `set`s aren't immutable.